# Python Slider Value

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a Scale in my GUI which I'm trying to get continuous values from. Below is my code.

```
from Tkinter import *
class Application(Frame):
   def getVoltage(self):
      print self.voltage_scale.get()
   def createWidgets(self):
      self.voltage_scale = Scale(self)
      self.voltage_scale["from_"] = 0
      self.voltage_scale["to"] = 32
      self.voltage_scale["orient"] = "horizontal"
      self.voltage_scale["command"] = self.getVoltage
      self.voltage_scale.grid(column=0,row=9)
   def __init__(self,Master=None)
      Frame.__init__(self,master)
      self.createWidgets()
      self.tn = None
root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

When I run the code above, and start moving my slider, I get an error that says:

```
getVoltage() takes exactly 1 argument, two was given
```

All I'm trying to do is get the value of the slider. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`def getVoltage(self, event_arg):` will fix that. The command of some tk controls is passed some event data as an extra argument

Comment: Outstanding! Works Perfect!